Get an external report link of test execution in selenium testNG when Jar file is executed, in the integration testing
I'm working on executing testNG suite through executable jar with dependencies. When we run we see extent reports i.e., emailable report . Now for our application, which has microservice architecture. We are following procedure of creating a executable jar of selenium project and running the tests. So, once we run the jar .I want a report to be shown once execution is completed. Is there any possible way with maven or any other dependency?
Thanks
I have added the listeners for now , to just show tests status. If there are some tests failing, We wanted some screenshots to check out the on the report . Looking for a workaround , if there is some method to get the external report of the tests.
